# Python: Extract value as it appears in Excel cell not underlying number

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Is it possible to extract the formatted value as it appears in the MS Excel cell and NOT the underlying number?

Example 1: Extract value from cell A1

```
Excel cell shows: 0.03 

Excel formula bar shows: 0.02827 

Python extracts: 0.02826999999999
```

I would like to extract the formatted "0.03" value

Example 2: Extract value from cell A1

```
Excel cell shows: BLANK

Excel formula bar shows: =B1

Python extracts: 0
```

I would like to extract the formatted BLANK value

I'm using "openpyxl" but haven't been able to solve my problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `data_only = True` when loading the workbook?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible because it would involve implementing a parser for the number format, which itself is not normative. Solutions in client code are easier.